# Visualizar el contenido de una función php en Smarty

Tags: php, funciones, variables

Tengo el resultado de un carro de compra en una función que está dentro de una clase a la que llamo así:

```
$_SESSION["mycarrito"]->imprime_mycarrito();
```

la función definida se halla en un archivo funciones.php

Tengo mi archivo carro.php donde cargo toda la librería Smarty  y hago display en mi archivo carro.tpl

Hasta ahora llamo las variables así:

```
$smarty->assign("variable", $variable, true);
```

Y las imprimo en .tpl así `{$variable}`

Qué sintaxis debo utilizar para imprimir el contenido de la función `imprime_mycarrito` dentro del .tpl?

No se si estoy tomando el camino correcto al usar .tpl para mostrar el carrito, acepto consejos.
Muchas gracias!!

Comment: haz intentado algo asi como `$smarty->assign("carrito", $_SESSION["mycarrito"]->imprime_mycarrito(), true);` ? es decir, asignar el resultado de la funcion a una variable? luego la imprimirias como `{$carrito}`...

Comment: Sí, pero no me tira

Comment: funciona pero me imprime la funcion desde el php, no responde desde {$print_carrito} y me coloca los datos por encima del <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Funciona pero me imprime la funcion desde el php, no responde desde {$print_carrito} y me coloca los datos por encima del  "*

me suena a que tu función lo que hace es enviar el contenido directo al documento, algo como

```
echo 'alguna cosa';
```

si quieres capturar eso sin que salga al documento intercepta la salida con **ob_start()** y sus funciones asocidas, **ob_get_clean** así la puedes asignar a una variable y hacer lo que quieres
http://php.net/manual/es/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: más bien la llamo $variable.='algo';
Pero lo que comentas sobre ob_start() me parece buena opción. Voy a echar un ojo a la documentación que me envías. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION["mycarrito"]=imprime_mycarrito();`

Asi le asignas el valor de la función, recuerda que esa función debe estar en el mismo documento en el que asignas el valor a la variable de sesión. Si no es así debes hacer un include_once de la clase que contiene esa función o llamarla de manera estática, eso depende de como lo hayas programado.

Por otro lado en el mismo documento en el que asignas ese valor a la variable de sesion debes hacer:

`$smarty->assign("carrito", $_SESSION["mycarrito"]);`

y tras inicializar todas tus variables de smarty desplegar el .tpl:

`$smarty->display('../ruta/a/tu/plantilla.tpl');`

despues en tu plantilla .tpl podras mostrar el contenido de {$carrito} pero la manera de hacerlo dependera del tipo que te devuelve la funcion `imprime_mycarrito();`

`//por ejemplo si te devuelve un array de objetos con los atributos nombre y precio puedes hacer:
        <table id="example">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>precio</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
     {foreach $carrito as $indice=>$r}
                <tr>
                    <td>{$r->nombre}</td>
                    <td>{$r->precio}</td>
                </tr>
     {/foreach}
            </tbody>
        </table>`

Si pones mas información acerca de la estructura que te devuelve tu función y como quieres mostrarlo te podría dar mas información.

Comment: Sí, es así como lo vengo haciendo. La clave estaba en ob_start